# Graph Instances in Java

Tags: java, optimization, graph

I am currently preparing to write my Bachelor´s Thesis on Improving heuristically created solutions to optimiziation problems with stochastic local search.

For this I already found instances of mixed graphs (with directed and undirected edges) stored in .dat files.

My question is now:
How do I use these files in Java? (sorry I only have basic Java knowledge)
I want to test local search methods on all these instances so do I store them in Objects? 
They are quit a lot so is there a method to maybe create a library of graphs and then execute the algorithms on the whole library?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: .dat is sadly a generic extension and doesn't say anything about the actual format of the data within it, so you'll have to figure that out first.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote my master thesis on Dynamic Graphs and implemented things you might be interested in. Feel free to have a look at my thesis: https://www.chianterastutte.eu/owncloud/index.php/s/a1tYJvpQVFWSOz9

If you want to access the code, you should talk to the University of Leicester, they wanted to open source.

In a nutshell: As far as I can see, the few standard file formats for graphs are not well supported by any Java library. And I never heard about a .dat format for graphs.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! so how did you use graphs in java? with matrizes?

Comment: So if I understand that correctly, I could use your library to create "static" graphs too? Like just mixed graphs with weighted edges that do not change over time

Comment: I extended the JGraphT library in order to support dynamic information (only needed for a time series of graphs) and defined my own, XML based file format. That will not help you in reading some given file, though...

Comment: Mmh ok, but thanks so far. I will check out JGraphT library then and maybe contact your university because I think I could use the code from your dissertation

Comment: At the end of the dissertation there are (protected) links to their SVN. Try to contact Prof. Erlebach for access.